# Fill HTML elements with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am trying to figure out the best way to JSONify a set of repeated HTML that I have with me.

I have the following piece of code that gets repeated for "n" number of times.

```
<article class="style2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <a href="http://www.google.com">
                <div class="article-thumb">
                    <img src="https://place-hold.it/370x231/5" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="post-excerpt">

                <h3><a href="http://www.google.com">This is my first article</a></h3>
                <div class="meta">
                    <span>by <a href="#" class="link">Benjamin K.</a></span>
                    <span>on Sep 23, 2016</span>
                    <span class="comment"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 1</span>
                </div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                <a href="http://www.google.com" class="small-title rmore">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

I want to create a template, something like this (suggestions welcome)

```
<article class="style2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <a href="">
                <div class="article-thumb">
                    <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="post-excerpt">

                <h3><a href=""></a></h3>
                <div class="meta">
                    <span>by <a href="" class="link"></a></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="comment"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> </span>
                </div>
                <p></p>
                <a href="" class="small-title rmore">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

and then dynamically generate this element based on a JSON file. The contents of the JSON will be similar to the following:

```
url = http://www.google.com
image = https://place-hold.it/370x231/5
title = This is my first article
author = Benjamin K.
date = Sep 23, 2016
abstract = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
comments = 1
```

CodePen https://codepen.io/iwant2learn/pen/PEmBMN

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should check templating libraries like underscore, handlebars etc for this. They have been precisely developed for this purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "template" really is fixed (no variants) and quite simple as what you posted... The [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method may be an interest for you.

Yes... As mentionned in comments, there is templating libs that exist. You should also look. But a simple way to do it by yourself, using just one jQuery method, is to give each of your template "field" a class.

Then populate a clone of your template with the jsons you have and append it to the document.

Notice the ".template" class I added in your CSS to hide the template.

```js
var myJSONarray = [
  {
    url : "http://www.google.com",
    image : "https://place-hold.it/370x231/5",
    title : "This is my first article",
    author : "Benjamin K.",
    date : "Sep 23, 2016",
    abstract : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco",
    comments : 1
  },{
    url : "https://learn.jquery.com/",
    image : "http://www.desartlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/jquery_logo.gif",
    title : "This is my first script!!!",
    author : "J. Q. Harry",
    date : "Dec 31, 2017",
    abstract : "You can do what you want, if you are a bit creative, my friend.",
    comments : 172
  }
];

$(document).ready(function(){

  for(i=0;i<myJSONarray.length;i++){

    var clone = $(".template").clone();
    clone.find(".template-url").attr("href",myJSONarray[i].url);
    clone.find(".template-title").find("a").html(myJSONarray[i].title);
    clone.find(".template-image").attr("src",myJSONarray[i].image);
    clone.find(".template-author").html(myJSONarray[i].author);
    clone.find(".template-date").html(myJSONarray[i].date);
    clone.find(".template-abstract").html(myJSONarray[i].abstract);
    clone.find(".template-comment").html('<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> '+myJSONarray[i].comments);
    clone.removeClass("template");

    $(".template-spot").append(clone);
  }
});
```

```css
.template{
  display:none;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-content {
  padding: 50px 0 57px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section-head {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.section-head h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

article.style2 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

article {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

article .article-thumb {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

article:hover .article-thumb {
  background: #000;
}

article .article-thumb img {
  width: 100%;
}

article .article-thumb img {
}

article .article-thumb:hover img {
}

article .post-excerpt {
  padding: 9px 0;
}

article .meta {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.meta span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #787878;
}


a.link:hover, a {
  color: #333;
}

a.link, a:hover {
  color: #33ccff;
}

.small-title {
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.10em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="inner-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-head">
        <h2>Latest Bits</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 template-spot">

          <article class="style2 template">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <a href="http://www.google.com" class="template-url">
                  <div class="article-thumb">
                    <img src="https://place-hold.it/370x231/5" class="img-responsive template-image" alt=""/>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="post-excerpt">

                  <h3 class="template-title"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="template-url">This is my first article</a></h3>
                  <div class="meta">
                    <span>by <a href="#" class="link template-author">Benjamin K.</a></span>
                    <span class="template-date">on Sep 23, 2016</span>
                    <span class="comment template-comment"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 1</span>
                  </div>
                  <p class="template-abstract">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="small-title rmore">Read More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
  
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rpmZMq?editors=1111) *(Updated with an infinite scroll)*

Comment: I found tons of examples with everybody telling how to use underscore or moustache (which is valid with its own reasons). For me, I needed something similar to what you showcased. Brilliant. Thanks a ton mate. I will try this out and if I have any questions, I will ask you.

Comment: Do you think there will be any performance impact if I have about 800+ similar items to create on a page using a json file?

Comment: I think there will be no more performance issue than with a templating lib... ;)

Comment: Thanks. In case I told you that I have to repeat this across several pages with a different json file in each page, but with the same template, will you recommend and an alternate approach or do you still suggest I go with the solution you proposed earlier. I am looking for a best practice to learn here.

Comment: That's just a JS loop... What can make your big page "lag" are the images... If there is something like 800... They better be light. But the same issue would occur with a templating lib anyway.

Comment: So can I initially load 10 articles at a time, and then when I scroll down, another 10 loads up. This way, I won't have to load everything at once. Is that the correct approach? How do I do it?

Comment: That's another question... But you could run the clone loop to load 10 articles from the jsons when the scrolled amount equals the page height minus the viewport.... Something like that.

Comment: I made fun with the templating script... I added an infinite scroll to it. I hope you will love it! ;) Have a look at this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/rpmZMq?editors=1011). And have a Happy new year!

Comment: This is awesome Louys. Thanks so much!! Have a Fabulous New Year!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myJSONArray = [{
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  image: "https://place-hold.it/370x231/5",
  title: "This is my first article",
  author: "Benjamin K.",
  date: "Sep 23, 2016",
  abstract: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco",
  comments: 1
}, {
  url: "https://learn.jquery.com/",
  image: "http://www.desartlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/jquery_logo.gif",
  title: "This is my first script!!!",
  author: "J. Q. Harry",
  date: "Dec 31, 2017",
  abstract: "You can do what you want, if you are a bit creative, my friend.",
  comments: 172
}];

$(document).ready(function() {

  for (const val of myJSONArray) {
    var clone = $(".template").clone();
    clone.find(".template-url").attr("href", val.url);
    clone.find(".template-title").find("a").html(val.title);
    clone.find(".template-image").attr("src", val.image);
    clone.find(".template-author").html(val.author);
    clone.find(".template-date").html(val.date);
    clone.find(".template-abstract").html(val.abstract);
    clone.find(".template-comment").html(`<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> ${val.comments}`);
    clone.removeClass("template");

    $(".template-spot").append(clone);
  }
});
```

```css
.template {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-content {
  padding: 50px 0 57px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section-head {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.section-head h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

article.style2 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

article {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

article .article-thumb {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

article:hover .article-thumb {
  background: #000;
}

article .article-thumb img {
  width: 100%;
}

article .article-thumb img {}

article .article-thumb:hover img {}

article .post-excerpt {
  padding: 9px 0;
}

article .meta {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.meta span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #787878;
}

a.link:hover,
a {
  color: #333;
}

a.link,
a:hover {
  color: #33ccff;
}

.small-title {
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.10em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="inner-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section-head">
        <h2>Latest Bits</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 template-spot">

          <article class="style2 template">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <a href="http://www.google.com" class="template-url">
                  <div class="article-thumb">
                    <img src="https://place-hold.it/370x231/5" class="img-responsive template-image" alt="" />
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="post-excerpt">

                  <h3 class="template-title"><a href="http://www.google.com" class="template-url">This is my first article</a></h3>
                  <div class="meta">
                    <span>by <a href="#" class="link template-author">Benjamin K.</a></span>
                    <span class="template-date">on Sep 23, 2016</span>
                    <span class="comment template-comment"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 1</span>
                  </div>
                  <p class="template-abstract">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
                  <a href="http://www.google.com" class="small-title rmore">Read More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>

        </div>

      </div>
```

Same as what Louys did but used `for..of` loop as it's cleaner.